What determines that a given Python type is coercible into a given pyarrow datatype?
For example:

I know a dictionary can be coerced into a struct; what else can be coerced into a struct? What determines whether a Python type is coercible into a pyarrow datatype? Convention? Documentation? Subclassing?
on subclassing: can I make a custom class a subclass of some pyarrow class so that my custom class is recognized by pyarrow as coercible into a pyarrow data type?


You might take a look here:  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html

@TimRoberts That does not answer my question. Consider the section on structs: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html#struct-arrays --- where is it explained why dict[str, PyArrowCoercible] and tuple[str, PyArrowCoercible] are coercible into a struct?
